# Problem with GridView in ASP.NET using VB.NET 2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

My problem is that when i try to insert a GridView in ASP.NET webpage it doesn't appear in the Browser.

Comment: Can you give us some more detail?  How are you binding data to the grid? Are you sure there's at least one row to show?  How are you testing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind data to it for it to display.  No data and it will not display anything.

Try this (assuming you have `AutoGenerateColumns` on):

```
yourGrid.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
yourGrid.DataBind();
```

If you still get no data, check to see that the control's `Visible` property is not set to `false`.  Also make sure that no parented controls that the `GridView` is contain in are set to hidden as well.

You can also try setting the `EmptyDataText` property on your `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="yourGrid" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No data" ...
```

**EDIT:** (based on comment)

```
Dim DR As OleDbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
yourGridNameHere.DataSource = DR
yourGridNameHere.DataBind()
```

Comment: This is my code :

Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & "BD.mdb")
Dim Command As OleDbCommand = Conn.CreateCommand()      
Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM voyage"
Conn.Open()
Dim DR As OleDbDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()

Now how must I do to link the GridView with the DataBase, so it will show some records ?